# LARAVEL - UPDATE

Tags: laravel

I was trying to create an edit/update button in my table of datas but it seems that the button didn't work properly, I've tried many solutions from the internet but I couldn't find anything that helped.

Here is my view

```
<body>
<header>
<div class="menu-wrap">
    <input type="checkbox" class="toggler">
    <div class="hamburger"><div></div></div>
        <div class="menu">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/create_item">Input Menu</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/country_input">Country</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/state_input">State</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">City</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>

<br />
<div class="container box">
    <h3 align="center">Input Data</h3><br />
    <form action="{{url('/create_item')}}" method="post">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group">
            Country : 
            <input type="text" name="country" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            State :
            <input type="text" name="state" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            City :
            <input type="text" name="city" required>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-center position-ref">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="button">
                    <div class="links">
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add">
                        <a href="http://127.0.0.1:8000/">Back</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

@if (session('alert'))
   <div class="alert alert-success">
       {{ session('alert') }}
   </div>
@endif

<table id="datas">
    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>State</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Manage</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach($data as $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $value-> id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value-> country }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value-> state }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value-> city }}</td>
            <td>
                <button data-id="{{$value->id}}" data-ecountry="{{$value->country}}" data-estate="{{$value->state}}" data-ecity="{{$value->city}}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="border:none">Edit</button>&nbsp;
                <a href="/deleteCreateItem/{{ $value->id }}"><button>Delete</button></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</table>
```

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button> -->

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color:#E8E8E8">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Edit Data</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form action="{{url('/create_item',$value->id)}}" method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH" />
            <div class="form-group">
                Country : 
                <input type="text" name="country" id="country" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                State :
                <input type="text" name="state" id="state" required>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                City :
                <input type="text" name="city" id="city" required>
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <!-- <a href="/updateItem/{{ $value->id }}"><button>Save Changes</button></a> -->
        <div class="flex-center position-ref">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="button">
                    <div class="links">
                        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save Changes">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var ecountry = button.data('ecountry') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var estate = button.data('estate') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        var ecity = button.data('ecity') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
        // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
        var modal = $(this)

        modal.find('.modal-body #country').val(ecountry)
        modal.find('.modal-body #state').val(estate)
        modal.find('.modal-body #city').val(ecity)
    })
</script>
```

I was using modal for the edit button

Here is my Router

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/create_item', function() {
    return view('create_item');
});

Route::post('/create_item','CreateItem@insert');

Route::get('/create_item','CreateItem@getData');

Route::post('/create_item/{id}','CreateItem@update');

Route::get('/deleteCreateItem/{id}','CreateItem@delete');
```

Here is my Controller

```
class CreateItem extends Controller
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    function insert(Request $req)
    {
        $country = $req->input('country');
        $state = $req->input('state');
        $city = $req->input('city');

        $data = array('country'=>$country,"state"=>$state,"city"=>$city);

        DB::table('country_state_city')->insert($data);

        return back()->with('alert','Data inputed successfully!');
    }

    function update(Request $req, $id)
    {
        DB::table('country_state_city')->where('id',$req->id)->update([
            'country' => $req->country,
            'state' => $req->state,
            'city' => $req->city
        ]);

        return back()->with('alert','Data updated successfully!');
    }

    function getData()
    {
        $data['data'] = DB::table('country_state_city')->get();

        if(count($data) > 0)
        {
            return view('create_item',$data);
        }
        else
        {
            return view('create_item');
        }
    }

    function delete($id)
    {
        DB::table('country_state_city')->where('id',$id)->delete();
        return redirect('/create_item')->with('alert','Data Deleted!');
    }
}
```

I was still confused about the router part and post/get ones

Comment: Please will you give a bit more information around "the button didn't work properly" i.e. how isn't it working properly? Also, please can you share/explain a little about with solutions you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: when i clicked the edit button, it displays the modal popup but when I clicked on the save changes it didn't do anything, I've tried to change the router, CreateItem@update, and I've tried to use <button> and <a href>

Comment: `it didn't do anything` - that suggests maybe your modal HTML is invalid so the form isn't submitted. Look at it in your browser's devtools, is it OK? Check the devtools network tab, is the form really not submitted?  Any errors on your console? Any errors in your Laravel, webserver, or PHP logs?  There's a lot of code in your question - you might bet a better response if you can create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - it will help you understand the problem better, and make it easier for others to help.

Comment: I would imagine this is because your submit button isn't inside the form.